# Не выводить изображение с помощью the_post_thumbnail() wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Пытаюсь получить миниатюру c помощью the_post_thumbnail(), а оно почему-то не работает. Мб кто-то встречался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать  ... и **минимальный код для воспроизведения** прямо в вопросе. Пожалуйста, приложите ваш код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
the_post_thumbnail_url();
```

Этот кусок хардкода, вернёт URL адрес, без рендеринга. Надеюсь тебе это было нужно.

Приминение:

```
<img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
```

Comment: Нет, дело в том что он вообще не работает почему-то

Comment: Посмотри в html коде, что выдаёт на выходе

Comment: И не стесняйся выяснить причину банально через `var_dump(the_post_thumbnail());die;`. Это многое скажет, о причине негодований )

Comment: null выводит var_dump